# Python Quandl: what's the difference between `quandl.get_table` and `using api`?

Tags: python, quandl

I'm about to use `quandl` for getting US stock data.

I think there are two ways to getting data

1. Use `quandl` library in `Python`

   import quandl
   quandl.get_table('WIKI/PRICES', ticker='FB')
2. using API

   ex) https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datatables/WIKI/PRICES?date=1999-11-18&ticker=FB&api_key=########

Is there any difference between these two? Doesn't it matter which one I use?

Comment: quick comment, I'm also using quandl and I'm facing a problem, using http calls (#2), I can transform the data to get the percent change. #1 I could not find in the documentation how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

In option 1 the call is made using http or sockets and the resultset is returned.
You do not have to worry about writing the plumbing code, you just import the lib.

In option 2 you will get the raw JSON data back from the http call and you will have to parse and process the data.

Depending on your situation you would use one of the options. Both do work!